# Javascript is not loaded in IE11 unless compatibility modes is turned on or off

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

### Situation

I maintain a webpage which uses Javascript to wrap a list of pictures into a slider.

The customer reported that the slider isn't loaded on IE11 (11.0.9600) unless put into compatibility mode. (As it seems the responsible Javascript isn't loaded or executed.)

### Analysis

I couldn't recreate this problem on or virtual machines at all.
But during a TeamViewer-session with the customer I was able to witness the following behavior:

1. Opening subpage with images
   => *Slider is not initialized*
2. Adding current domain to list of sites in compatibility mode
   => Page reloads and *Slider is initialized*

Strange enough, but here is more:

3. Loading another subpage (same domain) with images
   => *Slider isn't initialized* (again)
4. Remove the current domain to list of sites in compatibility mode
   => Page reloads and *Slider is initialized*

So it is *not* the compatibility mode itself causing or fixing the error, but *switching in on or off*.

### Question

The customer asks to fix that error serverside. But I have not a clue what might going on there. And since I can't recreate the error locally it's even harder to debug.

Also I'm unsure if there is anything I can do serverside.

Does anyone have any clue what might be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem:

there was a call of `new URL(...)` in the Javascript which isn't supported by the IE. That basically stopped the execution of the script including the initialization of he slider.

To why I wasn't able to recreate the issue locally:
The call above got executed only under certain circumstances like a specific browsing path. Really messed up.